# Web design arc circle effect

Tags: javascript, css, html, geometry, geometric-arc

Is there a way to emulate in HTML5/CSS (or JS) the arcs/circle like can be seen around the outside of this pic (the part where it says foundation, education, materials, etc)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can, it's a highly involved process with CSS3. You could use an algo in jQuery/JS to make it easier, but it is possible. [`transform:rotate`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform). The problem is, transform muddies the text too, so it's not clear.